# Using Auth0 user id for database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, auth0

I am a newb to RoR and I tried to throughly look this through before coming here for help. I am creating a web app and am using Auth0 for user authentication. The user information is saved on the Auth0 database and that's fine...but I want to create a database on my end of the app that allows the user to favorite a list of products that can be seen only to that specific user...if I'm making any sense.

So far for the dashboard I just have the basic set up where

```
class DashboardController < SecuredController


def show
    @user = session[:userinfo]
  end

  def destroy
    session[:userinfo] = nil if session[:userinfo]
    redirect_to root_url
  end

end
```

So nothing is really being done on my end but showing basic information of the user currently logged in.

Comment: To clarify, are you trying to save the user details in your database after they have authenticated via auth0?