# Can Auth0 ID_Token be used as a unique ID of a user for an app using Auth0 as Authentication?

Tags: jwt, aws-api-gateway, auth0

I plan to use Auth0 as my authentication service, and I'd like to know if Auth0 ID_Token, returned from Auth0 in Step 1, can be used as a unique ID for a user (i.e., it won't change during the whole life cycle of a registered user for my app).

[image]

In the above diagram, Action 3 will post an article (e.g, blog entry) to my app. And the app needs to be able to

1. show who published a particular article;
2. a user should be able to find out all the articles that she published.

Here are my questions:

1. Will the ID_Token from Auth0 always been same for a user, so that I can use that as my user_id?
2. If the answer to the above question is yes, how can Step 3 (post the article Restful call) carry such a token so that my Table_Article is able to use such an ID as a field?
3. Do I need maintain a Table_User in my DynamoDB on my AWS service side?

Comment: This question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40695511/choosing-user-id-in-application-that-relies-on-auth0-for-facebook-authentication answered my Question 1, i.e., there exist a unique ID from Auth0 that I can treat as user_id within my app. Still need answers to my question 2 and 3.

Comment: For question 3, the OP of this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38626438/using-auth0-user-id-for-database seemed to choose not to maintain a table on his service side. But I'd like to understand whether that's a sound decision for the above scenario.

Comment: You can pass the token in a header field which can then be passed on to the Lambda function if auth succeeds.

Comment: For your use-case, you can consider using [Cognito User Pools](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-integrate-with-cognito.html), which will pass all the identity information in the JWT itself. API Gateway provides first-part support for Cognito User Pools.

Comment: @Ritisha-AWS, is there an example code repo or tutorial for react developer to follow toward this route? thanks!

Comment: @chen Cognito user pools has a code repo with an example in react https://github.com/aws/amazon-cognito-identity-js/tree/master/examples/babel-webpack. There is a npm package for easy integration too https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-cognito

Comment: @Ritisha-AWS, thanks for the link. It only shows the client (browser) side of logic. What should I do on the API-Gateway side (I guess I need to configure something, such as authentication lambda)?